rtk-query having problem settting context value
I am using rtk-query to fetch data from API. I also have context that I am using for child components. Problem that I am facing is that context gets rendered before data is finished fetching. Here is my code:
export const defaultContext = {
    header: {},
};
export const MyContext = React.createContext(defaultContext);

export default function Page() {
    const [myData, setMyData] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        const { data, isError, isFetching, isLoading } = useFetchMyQuery();
        setMyData(data);

    }, [data, isError, isFetching, isLoading ]);

    if (isFetching) {
        return <Loader message={loadingText} />;
    }

    return (
      <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
        <MyContext.Provider value={myData}>
          <div className={`${styles.page} ${className}`}>
            <div className={styles.leftSide} />
            <div className={styles.rightSide} />
            {children}
          </div>
        </MyContext.Provider>
      </DndProvider>
    );
}

What I am doing wrong here? Tnx.

You're not supposed to use a useEffect here. Likewise, no state. It should look like this:
export const defaultContext = {
    header: {},
};
export const MyContext = React.createContext(defaultContext);

export default function Page() {
    const { data, isError, isFetching, isLoading } = useFetchMyQuery();

    if (isFetching) {
        return <Loader message={loadingText} />;
    }

    return (
      <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
        <MyContext.Provider value={data}>
          <div className={`${styles.page} ${className}`}>
            <div className={styles.leftSide} />
            <div className={styles.rightSide} />
            {children}
          </div>
        </MyContext.Provider>
      </DndProvider>
    );
}

That being said, the beauty of libraries like RTKQuery (or tanstack-query or useSWR) is that you don't need a separate context. You can just use the queries anywhere you need them. So, I'd skip the context as well, it's superfluous. Wherever in the component tree you need the data from useFetchMyQuery, just call the hook. RTKQuery is a context, you don't need to create a separate one.

We may need to decouple RTK query hooks from the child components and reduce the code duplication by using a context that works as a bridge.

What code duplication? The code duplication of using useFetchQuery everywhere will be replaced by the code duplication of useContext(MyContext). Just because you're using useFetchQuery doesn't mean you have to check for isLoading every time if you happen to know with certainty due to clear data flow that the data will already have been fetched and loaded in the cache. I sometimes create a custom hook like useMyData = () => useFetchQuery().data in those circumstances (still not extra context) and have child components use that. That being said, definitely do what works well for you!

Yes, you are right, I do the same by adding a custom-hook layer in between. The context will not add any value in this case.

@AdamJenkins Thanks, that got me going in the right direction. We should use queries anywhere we need them.
